# What does being "holomorphic at the cusps" mean?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, complex-manifolds

Let $G$ be a finite index subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.  Let $f$ be a modular form of a given weight on the upper half plane with respect to $G$. This means that

- $f$ is a holomorphic function $\mathscr H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
- For all $\tau \in G$, $f(\tau.z) = f(z)$.
- $f$ is holomorphic at the cusps.

I have never felt like I understood the meaning of this last condition.  Many textbooks I have looked at give ad hoc explanations that I either didn't understand or had no context for.

Is it possible to give a description in terms of complex manifolds?  I believe it should have something to do with the quotient space $G \backslash \mathscr H$, which can be given the structure of a complex manifold in such a way that the quotient $\mathscr H \rightarrow G \backslash \mathscr H$ is a submersion.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Crude-oreYixing-purple-black-mud-Zhu-holomorphic-hand-carving-censer-cup/32818397500.html

Comment: ..why? $\space$

Comment: They have holomorphic cups

Comment: That's..stupid $\space$

Comment: Well, yes......They're not all winners

Comment: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~taipale/modforms.pdf perhaps relevant for future users